# Turn off warnings via cmake?

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to turn off warnings about unused parameters during using cmake?
And do it in compiler independent fashion?

I mean that I don't want write custom code in CMakeLists.txt and I want to give a full trust to cmake, but I need a package, or cmake_policy about it.

Comment: See the answer for [How to set warning level in CMake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368811/how-to-set-warning-level-in-cmake) of @ruslo. CMake doesn't have this out-of-the-box but @ruslo has written a [`cross-platform warning suppression` CMake module](https://github.com/ruslo/sugar/wiki/Cross-platform-warning-suppression) (see the [list of supported warnings](https://github.com/ruslo/leathers/wiki/List); it does include e.g. `unused-variable`).

Comment: Thanks for link, what does it mean "no" in "list of supported warnings"?

Comment: The "no" just means that there is no such warning suppression flag for this compiler. But I think in your case it is supported for all the covered compiler toolchains: see `unused-parameter`