# Why does CMake split arguments differently for add_compile_options and target_compile_options?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to enable warnings in a CMake project. Using `target_compile_options` similar to what is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882216) works fine:

```
target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU,Clang>:-Wall -Wextra -pedantic>)
```

I have many targets, and I would like to apply these settings to all of them. So, I tried using `add_compile_options` instead:

```
add_compile_options($<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU,Clang>:-Wall -Wextra -pedantic>)
```

However, when I use this, I see that the compiler is passed `"\$<1:-Wall" -Wextra "-pedantic>"`, as if space-splitting occurred before expanding the generator expression. This confuses the compiler and the build fails.

I tried quoting the argument to `add_compile_commands`:

```
add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU,Clang>:-Wall -Wextra -pedantic>")
```

But when I do this, the compiler is passed a single `"-Wall -Wextra -pedantic"` argument, which also confuses it and causes the build to fail.

I can "distribute" out the generator expressions like this:

```
add_compile_options(
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU,Clang>:-Wall>
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU,Clang>:-Wextra>
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU,Clang>:-pedantic>
)
```

This works fine, and solves my immediate problem…

**…but,** the question remains: what is causing `add_compile_options` to work differently from `target_compile_options` here? Shouldn't their string-splitting semantics be identical?

Answer (score 3):

That is, because [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) is used to add compile options to the [COMPILE_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html#prop_dir:COMPILE_OPTIONS) list, a semicolon seperated list, whereas [`add_target_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) adds options to the [INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS) of datatype `property`.

You were so close! Your code works as soon as you replace spaces with semicolons:

```
add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU,Clang>:-Wall;-Wextra;-pedantic>")
```

And yes! I also think, that this behavior is inconsistent and that `add_compile_options` should work more similar to `target_compile_options`. Maybe somebody else can elaborate the history of that further, but my curiosity was satisfied when I found out, that `[^_]COMPILE_OPTIONS[^_]` appears much more frequently in the code, than `[^_]INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS[^_]` does: That means 121/40 at d231f429f10e9! From that I assume, that it has been there for longer and changing the way how it is implemented would very likely break existing build chains for some users and nobody wants that.