# How to enable MSVC compiler warnings for specific files with CMAKE

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, build-system

Here is a CMakeLists.txt for an  example project, which I am compiling with MSVC in VS2022:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(Example VERSION 1.0)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    # Only show warnings for the following files
    src/main.cpp
    src/foo.cpp
    src/bar.cpp
    src/header_only.hpp # Can I get warnings for standalone headers?
    # No warnings for this next file please
    lib/library.cpp
)

# I do not want to see any warnings from the compilation of example submodule
add_subdirectory(submodules/example_submodule)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PRIVATE submodules/example_submodule/include
)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE submodules/example_submodule/src
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC example_submodule
)
```

I want to reduce the amount of unimportant compiler warnings from third party files. Is it possible for me to only see compiler warnings from main.cpp, foo.cpp, bar.cpp and header_only.hpp and none from the standard library or the example submodule. And can you see warnings from standalone headers? I could see them when compiling with GCC but I can't get them to appear with MSVC.

Comment: "Can I get warnings for standalone headers?" - No, you cannot control warnings for a **header**. You may only control warnings for a **source file**, which is compiled. For enable warnings for all source files in a target, add compile options like `/W4` by using  `target_compile_options` command. Like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882216/3440745).